# how to move NSWindow to a particular screen?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

In my app I need to be able to move my app's windows between the screens programmatically. I'm working on my MacBookPro and I'm connected to DELL monitor. So what I want to do is to have a method that would move my app's window from my laptop screen to the external DELL one.

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[NSScreen screens]` gives you an array of NSScreens.  The screen at index 0 is the one that's got your menu on.

So pick the other screen from the array, find it's `visibleFrame` and change the frame of your window to go inside it.

Comment: The main screen is not necessarily the same screen that contains the menu bar or has its origin at (0, 0). The main screen refers to the screen containing the window that is currently receiving keyboard events. It is the main screen because it is the one with which the user is most likely interacting. (From Apple NSScreen Reference)

Answer (score 1):

Following Steve Waddicor's comment, I tried putting the following code in `override func viewDidLoad(){}` and I was able to display a window on the main screen, on my laptop.

By changing `screens[0]` to `screens[1]`, your window should be on your external display.
I hope this helps somebody.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
           //set up the main display as the display where window shows up
           let screens = NSScreen.screens
           var pos = NSPoint()
           pos.x = screens[0].visibleFrame.midX
           pos.y = screens[0].visibleFrame.midY
           self.view.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)
      }
```